# Node 4.1.0 TLSSocket issues

Tags: node.js, sockets

Strange behavior in Node with TLSSocket and tls.connect.

```
var port = 7000;
var host = '94.125.182.252'; //freenode
var tls = require('tls');
var net = require('net');

var socket = new net.Socket();
var secure;

secure = new tls.TLSSocket( socket,  {
  isServer: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});

// edit (left out of original post, but present in my test code, whoops)
secure.connect( {
  port: port,
  host: host
});

secure.setEncoding( 'utf8' );

secure.on( 'connect' , function() {
  console.log( 'connected' );
})

.on( 'secureConnect', function() {
  console.log( 'secure connect' );
})

.on( 'error', function( e ) {
  console.log( 'error', e );
})

.on( 'data', function( data ) {
  console.log( data );
});

if ( secure.isPaused() ) {
  console.log( 'socket was paused' );
  secure.resume();
}
```

This doesn't even attempt to connect and no error messages are produced. I have wireshark monitoring and there is no activity captured.

A different approach:

```
secure = tls.connect( {
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  host: host,
  port: port,
  socket: socket
});
```

Same story, nothing captured, no errors. If I remove the `socket: socket` aspect above it will connect. This makes some sense as the docs state that if the socket option is specified it will ignore port and host. The above works on my previous Node version( 0.12.7).

If I want to use the existing socket I have to tell it to connect before calling tls.connect.

```
socket.connect( {
  port: port,
  host: host
});

secure = tls.connect( {
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  socket: socket
});
```

This doesn't seem proper.
Passing a connecting socket to tls.TLSSocket( socket, ...) seems to have no effect.
The 'connect' event is fired but I imagine that is not related to TLSSocket.
I could not get tls.TLSSocket(...) to work on previous Node iterations.
Stepping through with node debug did not expose any obvious problems.

The options for net.Socket([options]) don't seem to accept a port or host for configuring until you try to connect, and trying to connect before passing to tls.connect seems counter intuitive. It would suggest that is not the intended usage.

So my questions would be:

What am I doing wrong with tls.TLSSocket() or perhaps is it a bug?

Am I correct to assume that passing an existing socket into tls.connect() is for already established connections switching protocol? If not, whats the proper way to assign a port and host?

Edit:

As per suggestion:

```
secure = tls.connect( {
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  socket: socket
});


socket.connect( {
  port: port, 
  host: host
});
```

This works.

```
secure = new tls.TLSSocket( socket , {
  isServer: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});

socket.connect( {
  port: port,
  host: host
});
```

Unfortunately this does not work. A 'connect' event is emitted, never a 'secureConnect' and never any other events or data.

Answer (score 3):

In your first two (non-working) examples, you only created a socket and never started actually connected it. Add a `socket.connect();` at the end of your original code and it should work fine.

`tls.connect()` when passed a plain socket, does not actually call `socket.connect();` internally, it merely sets up to start listening for data on the socket so it can decrypt incoming data properly.