# How to use Node.js' TLSSocket to connect (and reconnect) to a server?

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl

I have a [toy IRC bot](https://github.com/VirtualWolf/weatherbot) that I've been hacking on, and it has the ability to connect to multiple servers at once, both unencrypted and over TLS. Originally my [connection code looked like this](https://github.com/VirtualWolf/weatherbot/blob/a64953cb2e6e31b566435be08f3ba4f61914fee0/src/lib/weatherbot.ts#L36-L38):

```js
constructor({host, port, tlsEnabled, nick, channels}: {host: string, port: number, tlsEnabled: boolean, nick: string, channels: Channels}) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port
        ? port
        : tlsEnabled
            ? 6697
            : 6667;
    this.tlsEnabled = tlsEnabled;
    this.nick = nick;
    this.channels = channels;

    this.client = this.tlsEnabled
        ? tls.connect({host: this.host, port: this.port, timeout: 180000}, () => this.sendClientRegistration())
        : net.connect({host: this.host, port: this.port, timeout: 180000}, () => this.sendClientRegistration());

    [...]

    this.client.on('close', (hadError) => {
        logMessage('INFO', this.host, `Connection to ${host} closed`);

        try {
            setTimeout(() => this.client.connect({host: this.host, port: this.port}, () => this.sendClientRegistration()), 60000);
        } catch (err) {
            logMessage('INFO', this.host, `Failed to reconnect to ${this.host}`);
        }
    });
}
```

It mostly worked fine, except if the connection to the server was interrupted for long enough I'd end up with a `MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 connect listeners added to [Socket]` message and it'd never reconnect.

I [refactored the connection code](https://github.com/VirtualWolf/weatherbot/blob/74551148efa36425e524eed86e6baa7c52af578f/src/lib/weatherbot.ts#L36-L73) to look like this:

```js
constructor({host, port, tlsEnabled, nick, channels}: {host: string, port: number, tlsEnabled: boolean, nick: string, channels: Channels}) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port
        ? port
        : tlsEnabled
            ? 6697
            : 6667;
    this.tlsEnabled = tlsEnabled;
    this.nick = nick;
    this.channels = channels;

    this.client = this.tlsEnabled
        ? new tls.TLSSocket(new net.Socket())
        : new net.Socket();

    [...]

    this.client.on('close', () => {
        logMessage('INFO', this.host, `Connection to ${host} closed`);

        try {
            setTimeout(() => this.connect(), 60000);
        } catch (err) {
            logMessage('INFO', this.host, `Failed to reconnect to ${this.host}`);
        }
    });

    this.connect();
}

connect() {
    this.client.connect({host: this.host, port: this.port});
}
```

And while that works perfectly for a non-TLS connection and will happily try to reconnect as many times as needed without creating too many event listeners, with a TLS connection it doesn't even try to connect, if I have one single TLS connection in my config, the application just exits cleanly immediately.

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707948/node-4-1-0-tlssocket-issues) that seems very similar, but I haven't had any luck figuring out how to actually get it working for my case, and the Node.js TLS documentation hasn't been enlightening either. [It says this](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/tls.html#tlsconnectoptions-callback) for the `socket` option for `tls.connect()`:

> `socket <stream.Duplex>` Establish secure connection on a given socket rather than creating a new socket. Typically, this is an instance of `net.Socket`, but any `Duplex` stream is allowed. If this option is specified, `path`, `host` and `port` are ignored, except for certificate validation. Usually, a socket is already connected when passed to `tls.connect()`, but it can be connected later. Connection/disconnection/destruction of `socket` is the user's responsibility; calling `tls.connect()` will not cause `net.connect()` to be called.

I updated the connection code again to look like this:

```js
constructor({host, port, tlsEnabled, nick, channels}: {host: string, port: number, tlsEnabled: boolean, nick: string, channels: Channels}) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port
        ? port
        : tlsEnabled
            ? 6697
            : 6667;
    this.tlsEnabled = tlsEnabled;
    this.nick = nick;
    this.channels = channels;

    this.client = new net.Socket();

    [...]

    this.connect();
}

connect() {
    if (this.tlsEnabled) {
        tls.connect({
            socket: this.client,
        })
    }

    this.client.connect({host: this.host, port: this.port});
}
```

But clearly I'm doing it wrong because I end up with `Error: read ECONNRESET` error in my application, and the IRC server `ngircd` says `SSL protocol error: SSL_accept (error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number)`.

How is `tls.connect()` meant to work when you pass an existing socket?